# How do I create a strongly typed view page using ASP.NET MVC VB.NET XML Literals View Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, xml-literals, viewengine

I am using the ASP.NET MVC VB.NET XML Literals View Engine created by Dmitry Robsman and described on his blog in this post.

http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2008/12/29/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-using-vb-net-xml-literals.aspx

I would like to create strongly typed view pages using this view engine, but it doesn't seem to contain the requisite VbView(Of TModel) generic type by which I would create such a view class.

The end result should look something like this:

```
Namespace Views.Client
    Public Class Details(Of Models.Client)
        Inherits SiteMaster

        Public Overrides Function RenderContent() As XElement
            Return _
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Fields</legend>
                <p>
                    FirstName:
                    <%= Xhtml.Encode(Model.FirstName) %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    MiddleName:
                    <%= Xhtml.Encode(Model.MiddleName) %>
                </p>
                <p>
                    LastName:
                    <%= Xhtml.Encode(Model.LastName) %>
                </p>
            <fieldset>
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Once there is a VbView(Of TModel) class that inherits from Dmitry's VbView class, I will need help figuring out how to hook that up so that it works with standard MVC controllers that call the view like this.

```
Function Details(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Dim c = SomeGetClientFunction(id)
    Return View(c)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the ASP.NET MVC C# source code and was able to figure out how to create the VbView(Of TModel) class by mirroring some of that structure.  I have created a project on CodePlex that contains that new class and a couple other changes that enhance what Dmitry did.  http://vbmvc.codeplex.com